# Why was it ever thought multi layer perceptrons couldn't implement XOR functions?

Tags: machine-learning, history, perceptron

As I understand it the [Perceptrons books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptrons_(book)) helped start the "AI Winter" because the authors claimed that multilayer perceptrons couldn't implement non linearly separable functions like XOR.

However it was know single perceptrons could implement AND, OR and NAND, and that in general XOR = NAND (AND) OR.

So how come it wasn't easy to see that by combining multiple perceptrons XOR could be implemented?

(I know this is quite history based, but it feels like I'm missing something that will help me understand them better)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that your question is based on a false premise.  You should get a copy of the 1969 book *Perceptrons* by Minsky and Papert and read it to see the claims that they did make, which certainly don't include the claim that  "multilayer perceptrons couldn't implement non linearly separable functions like XOR."

Answer (score 0):

> because the authors claimed that multilayer perceptrons couldn't implement non linearly separable functions like XOR

I thought you were misled by the misnomer multilayer perceptrons. The multilayer perceptron refers to pure linear layers, but sometimes we call feedforward networks(including nonlinear neurons) multilayer perceptrons.

It is true that pure linear multilayer perceptrons cannot implement XOR functions just as we cannot do that using single layer pure linear multilayer perceptrons because pure multilayer perceptrons can be just reduced to single layer pure linear perceptrons with appropriate weights but that cannot exhibit nonlinear decision boundaries.